# Selenium .click() not working. Receiving error 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

.click() is not working properly and returns an error: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint
import pandas as pd

chromedriver_path = 'C:/Users/Enrico/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path)
sleep(2)
webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
sleep(3)

username = webdriver.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('username')
password = webdriver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('password')
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
sleep(3)

notnow = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(13) > div > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm')
notnow.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect. You should not be using

```
notnow = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(13) > div > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm')
```

Instead of find_elements_by_css_selector , you should be using find_element_by_css_selector.

Unless if you are expecting notnow to be a list of elements return , you should do a loop and click the right element instead. Something like this

```
elements = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(13) > div > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm')

for element in elements:
    element.click()
```

Comment: I am trying to get past the notification pop-up which has two different elements. One is not now. I took the css for the button and attempted to use .click() to select the not now button but .click() does not work at all, even on single elements.

Answer (score 0):

`.find_elements*` return elements list, so you need put index before call `.click()` method.

```
notnow = webdriver.find_elements_by_css_selector('body > div:nth-child(13) > div > div > div > div.mt3GC > button.aOOlW.HoLwm')

print(len(notnow))
if len(notnow) > 0:
    notnow[0].click()
else:
    print('element not found')
```

The above assumse you want click first element.

Comment: Hi, When I attempt that I get the error: list index out of range.

Comment: @EnricoShippole Try `print(len(notnow))`, if the result is `0`, it seem like you are using wrong locator or element you mean not appear. Please try and info to me again.

Comment: @EnricoShippole I've updated the answer, please looks the `if` conditional.

Comment: @EnricoShippole Or can you provide the HTML `notnow`? Maybe we can change the locator.

Comment: Hi, I actually just got out of the Emergency Room. I am doing better now. I will check the code and let you know what I receive. I appreciate your help. @frianH

Comment: I ran your answer. I did receive the output: 0, element not found. I will attempt to locate the correct element to bypass the pop up notification. Thank you.